# Inserting rich text into a JFace TableViewer in Eclipse v3.3

Tags: eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

The `StyledCellLabelProvider` is available in 3.5 onwards, but alas I am anchored to a platform that must use v3.3. Can anyone say how I might display rich text in a field of a JFace `TableViewer`?

Is it even possible at all?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the source for 3.5 and modify it so it works with 3.3. The StyledCellLabelProvider is not very complex (only 500 lines of code) and you should be able to make it work with 3.3 with only a few modifications.